# How to load Tab Pages, Listboxes to Tabpages, and Checkboxes to ListBoxes with specific name and location

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

I assumed adding ListBoxItems or PageControls with .Add() would have done a default, but my pages and listboxes do not populate with checkboxes.

```
    //
        public void InstantiateMyTabPage()
        {
            string rootPath = @"C:\Users\Director\Documents\TestCertApp";
        //1@  
            string[] myDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(rootPath, "-", 
            SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            foreach (string dir in myDirs)
            {

//Here, I grab each dir in myDir in rootpath and make string wow = to that //string value at 1@
                string wow = Path.GetDirectoryName(dir);
                TabPage newPage = new TabPage();

                newPage.Text = wow;
                newPage.Name = wow;
                tabControlFolders.TabPages.Add(wow);



//Just to test. Doesn't work either.
                MessageBox.Show(wow);
            }
        }



//Skip listboxes

//CheckBoxes
        public void InstantiateMyCheckBox()
        {


            string subFold = 
            @"C:\Users\Director\Documents\TestCertApp\TestSub";

            var myFolders = Directory.GetFiles(subFold, " - ", 
            SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);



//for each certificate file create a check box named just the file name 

            foreach (string file in myFolders)
            {
                string wow2 = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
                CheckBox thisBox = new CheckBox();
                thisBox.Text = wow2;
                thisBox.Name = wow2;
                listColumn1.Items.Add(wow2);

                //These do not show up in the listboxes I currently have.





            }
        }
```

Expected for pages to load by calling, then call for checkboxes to fill listboxes. 
What I have is two empty listboxes and a tabpage with no name.

Comment: Is this WinForms?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention